# How to merge changes back to the HEAD

Tags: git, github

Here is what I did

I create a branch `abc`. Then I created two text files `one.txt and two.txt`. Then I commit them to branch `abc`. Then I removed the file one.txt from the branch and commit these changes to the branch. **Now I want to merge these changes back into the HEAD**. How can I do this last part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, change back to the `master` branch:

```
git checkout master
```

Then, merge the branch `abc`:

```
git merge abc
```

Comment: I know but I am confused with term HEAD. It does not say merge it with the master branch.

Comment: HEAD is a pointer to the *current* branch head. When your current branch is `abc`, HEAD points to the same place as `abc`. When the current branch is `master`, HEAD points to the same place as `master`. It doesn't make sense to "merge with HEAD", because you're already there.

Comment: @al0neevenings, Just do `$ cat .git/HEAD` in your work tree to get the idea.